# (Navegación web) iniciar sesión y lectura de datos. ¿Se puede hacer esto con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, navigation

Me gustaría saber si es posible hacer esto con python. Sé que se pueden leer ciertos datos de páginas web usando Beautiful Soup, pero lo que yo quiero hacer es un poco mas complejo.

1º-Iniciar una sesión en la web (rellenado un formulario como este)

```
<form action="/login.php">
  User:<br>
  <input type="text" name="usr" value="">
  <br>
  Pasword:<br>
  <input type="text" name="pass" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

2º-Entrar en uno de los enlaces de la página principal que me lleva a una base de datos. (ago mas o menos así)

```
<span id="divMenus" style="position:absolute; ">
<ul id="navmenu">
<li><a href="./data_base.aspx" target="_blank"></a></li>
</ul>
</span>
```

3º-Seleccionar campos en un Selector (algo como esto)

```
<select id="Campos" class="combo" style="width: 200px;" onchange="Campos_onchange();">
<option value="315">Campo1</option>
<option value="158">Campo2</option>
<option value="902">Campo3</option>
</select>
```

4º-Simular un ENTER en el select para que se ejecute **Campos_onchange()** y se generé una tabla con los datos que me interesan (algo así).

```
<table id="tabla_nombres">
  <tr>
    <th>Nombre1</th>
    <th>Nombre2</th>
    <th>Nombre3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="./info1.aspx">Link1</a></td>
    <td><a href="./info2.aspx">Link1</a></td>
    <td><a href="./info3.aspx">Link2</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

5º-Leer los datos de la tabla anterior.

6º-En una de las columnas de esa tabla hay links que debería abrir (Se abre otra página a parte que también contiene una tabla con datos que interesan).

Creo que puede ser importate decir que la página es **totalmente dinámica**. Su código está completamente hecho en **JavaScript + AJAX**.

### Si es posible hacer algo así con Python me gustaría saber que modulos/librerias tengo usar.

### ----------------------------------ACTUALIZACION------------------------------

Al final estoy usando un "bot" tipo autoit para hacerlo... el problema es que no puedo usar el PC mientras trabaja y tarda horas... Necesito una solución que trabaje en segundo plano. Me da igual lo que sea mintras funcione... Python, C++, JavaStript.... cualquier cosa con tal de que se pueda automatizar la navegación web...

Comment: Por supuesto que se puede, el formulario puedes rellenarlo llamando a la url del action del formulario junto a ?parametros, en tu caso sería: login.php?usr=usuario&pass=password.

Comment: ¿Y la sesión se mantine abierta mientras dure la ejecución de mi script y aunque abra otros links?¿Que modulos tengo que importar para hacerlo?

Comment: léete esto: http://docs.python-requests.org/es/latest/ y se resolverán algunas de las dudas :)

Comment: La sesión se mantendrá si en las peticiones envias las cabeceras que te devuelve el login

Comment: Muchas gracias @Antoni Cobos

Comment: De nada, respecto a seleccionar campos con python, ahí no se qué hacer, con jqery es muy fácil, pero con python lo desconozco. Ahí no puedo ayudarte

Comment: Bueno, pero por el momento ya has hecho un gran aporte!! :-) A lo mejor aparece alguien mas por aquí y nos resulve esa duda!!

Comment: Necesitas que tu script interactue con el navegador y el motor javascript. Es algo bastante habitual cuando se quiere hacer pruebas de integración y de carga. El método depende del lenguaje y nivel de automatización que necesites. Uno de frameworks más completos y utilizados sería [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) con sus [*bindings* para python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Mechas gracias @ChemaCortes.